# Javascript error for dummies

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm pretty new in jQuery and programming in general!

I'm trying to do a multilingual webpage, but I have a problem.

Following code results in an:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

on line 10??

What is the error in this code fragment?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var language_cookie = $.cookie("Languge");
        if ((language_cookie1 == null))
            $.cookie("Language", "ENG", {expires: 10});
});

$(document).load(function(){
        var language_cookie1 = $.cookie("Languge");

        if (language_cookie1 == "ENG")
            $("th", $("#table_select_language").html.("Select your language"));

});
```

This is my javascript file in the  tag in the  element.
I have regularly included the jQuery and the jQuery cookie plugin.

Comment: What you want to do if the cookie tells ENG?

Comment: in fact it should be `html(`

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery nor cookies ...

Comment: if the cookie tells eng i want to change all the text of the page to be in english, and i want to do the same for other 3 or 4 languages.
is this the good way to do this?
THX :D

Answer (score 2):

This is some mess):

```
$("th", $("#table_select_language").html.("Select your language"));
```

It should look like:

```
$("th", $("#table_select_language")).html("Select your language");
```

Answer (score 0):

You write this. more cleaner:

```
$("#table_select_language th").html("Select your language");
```

Comment: now i havn't got errors but the <th> element of the table is still not changing and i can't figure why?